# One Observable should emit items based on another Observable emitted items and both Observables are not connected

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-kotlin2

I have two different Observables which behaves as

Observable one behavior -> This will get created and one DisposableObserver will get subscribed to it and reacts to items emitted by the Observable One. This will be running continuously until app is closed.

Observable two behavior -> This will get created and get subscribed to a different Observer in a different time and after subscription this should emit values based on values emitted by Observable one after Observable two is subscribed. Once job is done Observable two subscription will be disposed but Observable one should continue.

How can I make second Observable emit values based on Observable one emitted values and dispose it after complete ?

Answer (score 1):

If `observableOne` can have only one subscription, you can do it a couple of ways. The simplest method is to introduce a `Subject`; it will be subscribed to `observableOne` and all other subscribers will subscribe to the subject:

```
PublishSubject<DataType> observableOneStream = PublishSubject.create();

observableOne
  .subscribe( observableOneStream );
...
observableOneStream.subscribe( firstSubscription );
...
observableOneStream.subscribe( secondSubscription );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `flatMap` values from Observable one into Observable two.

```
observableOne.flatMap(obsOneValue -> observableTwo(obsOneValue))
        .subscribe(obsTwoValue -> {

        });
```

then you can have method `Observable<ObsTwoValue> observableTwo(ObsOneValue obsOneValue)` which will create Observable two based on Observable one emissions.